# Why doesn't *ptr++ change the value of the pointee, but (*ptr)++ does?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was writing this program

```
   int x = 10;
   int *yptr;
   yptr = &x;
   cout << "The address yptr points to = " << yptr;
   cout << "The contents yptr points to =" << *yptr ;
   (*yptr)++ ;  
   cout << "After increment, the contents are: " << *yptr;
   cout << "The value of x is = " << x ;
```

Value increased of x from 10 to 11.
But when I write

```
 *yptr ++ ;
```

Value did not increase, why?

Comment: This title is not very descriptive of the issue at hand.

Comment: Hint: Why did you use parentheses in the first example?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes please suggest me any other title.

Comment: @0x499602D2 i have seen that example in a book. Actually i am new with c/c++.

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the operator precedence table.  Without parentheses, monadic operators have right to left precedence (from pg 49 of K&R 1978 ed) so it will do the ++ before the *.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ language the grouping between operators and their operands is defined by the grammar. For convenience, this grouping is often expressed in simplified linear form called *operator precedence*. In C++ postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix/unary ones. So, in your case `*yptr++` stands for `*(yptr++)`, since postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`. The `++` operator is applied directly to `yptr` and `*` is applied to the result of `yptr++`.

When you added the extra `()`, you completely changed the expression and re-grouped the operators and operands. In `(*yptr)++` you forcefully associated the `*` with `yptr`. Now, `*` operator is applied directly to `yptr` and `++` is applied to the result of `*yptr`. Hence the change in the behavior.

In other words, the answer to your "why?" question is: because you explicitly asked the compiler make that change. The original expression was equivalent to `*(yptr++)` and you changed it to `(*yptr)++`. These are two completely different expressions with completely different meanings.

P.S. Note that the sequencing rules of C++ language does not generally allow one to describe the behavior of built-in operators in therms of what is evaluated "first" and want is evaluated "next". It is tempting to describe behavior of these expressions in therms of "`++` works first, `*` works next", but in general case such description are incorrect and will only lead to further confusion down the road.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `(*yptr)++` first `(*yptr)` is fetched because `()` has higher precedence than `++`, which is `10` and then `++` operator is applied, resulting `11`. When you write `*y ++;`, first `y++` is evaluated as `++` has higher precedence. That means the address is increased, then the content is fetched for `*` operator instead of incrementing the content. Learn [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: trying to fetch the content of `y+1` is not undefined behavior. It just fetches the content of the address with the given number.

Comment: y++ will return the current value of y before incrementing it. (++y) will return the value of y after increment.

Answer (score 0):

`(*ptr)++` increment the value that saved into ptr.
Like this

```
int *ptr;
*ptr =1;
(*ptr)++; 
std::cout<< *ptr; //out put will be 2
```

BUT
`*ptr++` increment the address of the usually for char pointer variables.
Like this

```
char *ptr = "Hello";
while(*ptr++)
     std::cout<<*ptr; //out put will be ello
```